# Java | Posing Boolean expressions on hashMap entries

Tags: java, hashmap, expression, logical-operators, boolean-expression

I have a **hashMap** that contains "term" as **key** and "documents list" as **values**.

Eg:

```
KEY::VALUE
afternoon::Doc2
activities::Doc1, Doc2, Doc3
admissions::Doc1, Doc2, Doc4, Doc5
alternate::Doc5
```

I need to pass boolean expressions against the terms and fetch the matching documents. This expression will be passed through another string variable.

Eg:

```
(afternoon AND activities) OR alternate => Doc2, Doc5
(afternoon AND activities) OR (admissions AND alternate) => Doc2, Doc5
activities AND NOT afternoon = > Doc1, Doc3
```

Are there any functions in Java for such operations? Any external libraries will work too.
A code snippet will help me a lot since my assignment is due tomorrow & this is the final step of my solution.

Comment: Are the operations fixed/static? Or they are just examples, comming from some text bar?

Comment: If the operations are fixed logical operations, you could use Enums to map them to their corresponding logic

Comment: Expressions may change for every run. I have just given example here to explain the desired output.

Comment: If expressions comes as free text, then I think Your assignment may be in danger :( SOme solutions: You may use some inmemory DB (e.g H2, sqlite,...), You can use Antlr (hard to do it relatively fast) or You can write some simple parser/evaluator by Your own just for AND, OR, NOT.

Comment: This is the final step. So if it works only for AND, that is fine too. I can submit and can get grades for the rest of my work. But without this last part, my assignment will be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the map values and find all the keys corresponding to that value, to make a `Map<String, Set<String>>` where the key is eg. Doc1 and the value is eg. activities,admissions. Represent each expression as a `Predicate<Set<String>>`, which looks at a set of terms and decides whether it matches the expression.

Now,

```
map.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> expression.test(e.getValue())).map(Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

returns the list of documents matching a term expression

Comment: I think that using Predicates here is the easiest part. The key thing in the problem is to transform a free text into Predicates chain

Comment: @zolv I'm assuming that problem is already solved, eg. he has a long list of predicates and can hard-code them.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you want to achieve union and intersection of list elements for boolean expressions.
You can write a custom method like

```
    public Set<Doc> andOp(Set<Doc> list1, Set<String> Doc) {
    if(list1.isEmpty() || list2.isEmpty())
        return new HashSet<>();

    Set<Doc> result = new HashSet<>();
    Iterator<Doc> it = list1.iterator();
    while( it.hasNext()) {
        Doc Doc1 = it.next();
        if(list2.contains(Doc))
            result.add(Doc);
    }
    return result;
}

public Set<Doc> orOp(Set<Doc> list1, Set<Doc> list2) {
    if(list1.isEmpty()) return list2;
    if(list2.isEmpty()) return list1;

    Set<Doc> result = new HashSet<>();

    result.addAll(list1);
    result.addAll(list2);
    return result;
}
```

So, the resultant expression for (afternoon AND activities) OR (admissions AND admissions) would be

```
Set<Doc> doc1 = andOp(map.get("activities"), map.get("afternoon"));
Set<Doc> doc2 = andOp(map.get("admissions"), map.get("admissions"));
doc1 = orOp(doc1, doc2);
```